# Need help on insert comma separated data in mysql database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

Demo data which already have in the database table:

```
INSERT INTO `csvtbl` (`ID`, `SKU`, `Product_Name`, `Model`, `Make`, `Year_From`, `Year_To`) VALUES
(1, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Galaxie', 'Ford', '1960', '1965'),
(2, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Thunderbird ', 'Fordtrest', '1960', '1965');
```

I have using below code and inserted years with comma(,) separated in table:

```
INSERT INTO `diff_yearstbl` (`ID`, `SKU`, `Product_Name`, `Model`, `Make`, `Year`) VALUES
(1, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Galaxie', 'Ford', '1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965'),
(2, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Thunderbird ', 'Fordtrest', '1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965');
```

Years data are working good, but I want to insert data Make and Model like same as Years, But this time just insert the data with comma (,) separated in one row like below example using SKU field. So need to merge the above two record in one row like below record.

```
INSERT INTO `diff_yearstbl` (`ID`, `SKU`, `Product_Name`, `Model`, `Make`, `Year`) VALUES
(1, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Galaxie, Thunderbird', 'Ford, Fordtrest' '1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965');
```

Below are the code what I have done:

```
    $query = "select Year_TO - Year_From as diff_years, ID, SKU,Product_Name,Model,Make,Year_From,Year_To from csvtbl";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connect );

//$result = $db->query($select_test)->fetchAll();

if (count($result) > 0) 
{

    while($QryRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $diff_years = $QryRow['diff_years'];
        $Year_From = $QryRow['Year_From'];
        $SKU = $QryRow['SKU'];
        $Product_Name = $QryRow['Product_Name'];
        $Model = $QryRow['Model'];
        $Make = $QryRow['Make'];

        $years= array();
        for ($x = $QryRow['Year_From']; $x <= $QryRow['Year_To']; $x++) 
        {           
            $years[] = $x;    
        }

        $query_insert = "INSERT INTO diff_yearstbl(SKU,Product_Name,Model,Make,Year) VALUES('".$SKU."','".$Product_Name."','".$Model."','".$Make."','".implode('|',$years)."')";
        $s_insert = mysql_query($query_insert, $connect ); 
    }
} 
else 
{
    echo "<p>Nothing matched your query.</p>";
}

    ?>
```

Please help about the same.

Comment: Switch simple quotes and double quotes in your `$query_insert`

Comment: You want to combine the years with make in one row?

Comment: you are getting years in array?

Comment: Yes i want insert the all years in the years column with  come (,) separated.

Comment: use serialize to insert array values

Comment: @ShakirKhan Yes, years getting in array and insert the year data in the year column with come (,) separated.

Comment: then implode your data like $YF = implode(',',$Year_From); and check echo $YR;

Comment: I think you can simply achieve it within your MySQL query only

Comment: Thanks to all who give me quick reply..

Comment: Consider storing the years in a separate table - a properly normalised approach

Comment: As a comment, this suggests you are denormalising your data to give yourself a comma separated field. These are generally a bad idea in SQL. It would be better to add an extra table listing the years for each sku / make / model (1 row per year / make / model). This will require system changes to access the data, but you will need that anyway with your current changes. Note you probably also should have a table of skus, a table of makes and a table of models, and for each other table that refers to these fields use the id from the relevant table rather than the text value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop from `$QryRow['Year_From']` to `$QryRow['Year_To']` and collect them all  before inserting them.

```
$years= array();
for ($x = $QryRow['Year_From']; $x <= $QryRow['Year_To']; $x++) 
{           
    $years[] = $x;    
}

$query_insert = "INSERT INTO diff_yearstbl(SKU,Product_Name,Model,Make,Year) VALUES('".$SKU."','".$Product_Name."','".$Model."','".$Make."','".implode(',',$years)."')";
$s_insert = mysql_query($query_insert, $connect );
```

---

**mysql_* is deprecated**  please use **mysqli_* or PDO**

Comment: I got the solutions using the above code. Thank You!

Comment: @NishantPatel Glad i helped.  Have a nice day.  please also take note `mysql_* is deprecated`

Comment: If i want to insert the '".implode(',',$Make)."') and '".implode(',',$Model)."') using the SKU. Then is it possible to do this using above code.

Now i want "(1, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Galaxie,Thunderbird', 'Ford, Fordtest' '1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965');" using the SKU field. Is it possible?

Comment: @NishantPatel i think it's possible.  can you update your question? i don't quite understand your next question/problem.

Comment: I have update my question. Please see and give me reply.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In a single SQL statement, coping with up to 100 years:-

```
INSERT INTO diff_yearstbl(SKU, Product_Name, Model, Make, Year) 
SELECT   SKU,
        Product_Name,
        Model,
        Make,
        GROUP_CONCAT(Year_From + tens.acnt * 10 + units.acnt) AS ayear
FROM csvtbl
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS acnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) tens
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS acnt UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) units
WHERE (Year_From + tens.acnt * 10 + units.acnt AS ayear) <= Year_TO
GROUP BY SKU,
        Product_Name,
        Model,
        Make
```

Answer (score 1):

Move out your insert code out of for loop

```
while($QryRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $diff_years = $QryRow['diff_years'];
        $Year_From = $QryRow['Year_From'];
        $SKU = $QryRow['SKU'];
        $Product_Name = $QryRow['Product_Name'];
        $Model = $QryRow['Model'];
        $Make = $QryRow['Make'];
        $YearCountList = array();
        for ($x = 0; $x <= $Year_From; $x++) {
            $YearCountList[] = $Year_From + $x;        
        } 

        $years=implode(',', $YearCountList); // insert comma separated values

        $query_insert = "INSERT INTO diff_yearstbl(SKU,Product_Name,Model,Make,Year) VALUES('".$SKU."','".$Product_Name."','".$Model."','".$Make."','".$years."')";
        $s_insert = mysql_query($query_insert, $connect );    
    }
```

Check This

Comment: @Nehal If i want to insert the '".implode(',',$Make)."') and '".implode(',',$Model)."') using the SKU. 

Then is it possible to do this using above code. Now i want insert data like 
"(1, 'C2AZ-3B584-AR', 'Power Steering Pump Seal Kit (Eaton Pump)', 'Galaxie,Thunderbird', 'Ford, Fordtest' '1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965');" 
using the SKU field. 

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Move out your insert code out of for loop