# How to insert comma separated time in MySql table

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I would like to add comma separated time's in time field (table)for example .

```
02:09:09,10:15:17 ,18:10:31,
```

what should i take data type for it time or varchar.

Someone please suggest me what can i do for this.

Comment: as obvious use varchar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help on insert comma separated data in mysql database using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498256/need-help-on-insert-comma-separated-data-in-mysql-database-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

use varchar datatype because it will allow multiple time with comma's